# Parse empty string as None with Json4s

Tags: scala, serialization, option-type, json4s

I know Json4s handles `Option`s on its own and most of the time this works great - for `Option[T]` it serializes `None` to missing value and reads missing value as `None` while automatically using the correct serializer/deserializer for `T` otherwise.

My problem is that I have a database where empty strings have been used as missing values, so I want to read those as `None`. A simple example:

```scala
case class Example(a: Option[Number])
val inputJson = """ {"a": ""} """
Serialization.read[Example](inputJson) // I want Example(None)
```

I thought I could do this pretty easily with a custom serializer, for example:

```scala
case object EmptyValueSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Option[_]](_ => (
  {case JString("") => None},
  {PartialFunction.empty}
))
```

This does work to read empty strings as `None`, however if the JSON value is *not* an empty string, it errors (ie, for the previous example, it would throw an error on `{"a": "5"}`). How can I get Json4s to continue parsing the value using it's default behavior if it's not an empty string?

Theoretically I thought about using a typetag `T` and adding a default case like `case v => Serialization.write[T](v)`, but I'm not sure if that's the best way and I also can't really wrap my head around what that would look like in code.

Comment: Though I have not used Json4s, but I am seeing you are just catching `""` by `case JString("") => None` in your custom Serialization. What about other ? I think you also need `case x@_:JsString => ???` and other types catching.

Comment: @MHJ I know how to catch other values (`case _ => ???`) the problem is I don't know if there's some way to get Json4s to keep trying with other serializers.

Comment: Any reason why you need to use Json4s specifically? It's really a pretty awful library compared to e. g. circe.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt That's what's in use - I don't have the power to change it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the pass but you just need another case statement

```
case object EmptyValueSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Option[_]](_ => (
  {
    case JString("") => None
    case JString(s) => Option(s)
  },
  {PartialFunction.empty}
))
```